How can I manage to allow only one application in MacOS Sonoma to access the internet
in a short while I will be reliant on a direct Iridium satellite connection only in order to get weather data.
The grib files are the only data I will process on my Macbook.
Now I know that usually once the Mac is connected to the internet all sorts of processes are sending and receiving data.
I dont want that to happen as I am on a limited data budget with the mentioned connection.
So I am wondering how I can most effectively prohibit the whole system to access the internet except that one process which will get the needed data.
Shall I

Configure the firewall
Edit the hostsfile
Use third party software like Little Snitch

Any pointers?

Do you have the technical expertise to configure the built-in firewall rules? If not, this would leave only one of your three options.

I know basic Unix firewall configuration. But I think not enough for this task.

Easiest would be to use TripMode.
You can block all or allow one, based on the network you are connected to.

Looks promising. Thank you.
